# How do I add a new Listing object to my array at index next in Java?

Tags: java, data-structures

```
public class DataStructure{ 

    private Listing[] data;  // an array of listing objects

     private int size = 100; 

     private int next = 0; 


 DataStructure(){

  // allocate the array to 100 elements 

    data = new Listing[100];
  }


 DataStructure(int numberofListings){

   this.numberofListings= numberofListings;

   }


public void addListing(Listing newListing){

 // how would I add a new Listing object to the array at index next

}

public void showAllListing(){ 

// this method will output the values of the data members of all Listing objects 

} 


 public static void main(String[] args){ 

  DataStructure obj1= new DataStructure();

  Listing l1= new Listing(); 




}






}
```

```html
for(i=0; i<100; i++) { 
 data[index];
}
```

Hello Everyone,

I am trying to figure out how I can add a new Listing object to my array at index next in my Java program. Would I have to use for loop and inside of that for loop, **would I have to manually set the new element to index named next** to a specific position in the array? I know that I would need to do something like to sample pseudocode above.  Also to test that new element and all the other elements are inside the array, I would need to call the showAll method, right? Can someone help me? Thanks!

Comment: It is unclear...

Comment: @davidxxx Here is my java code

Comment: `data[next] = newListing;`?

Comment: Maybe it's better to use List (e.g. ArrayList)? It will look like ``list.add(nextListingObject)``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use something like below :

- set the size with the constructor, and don't need to save in a variable (`data.length` will give it to you)
- when you add an element, you add it just next to the previous, then you increase by one the number of elements

---

```
public class DataStructure {

    private Listing[] data;

    private int next = 0;

    DataStructure(int numberofListings) {
        data = new Listing[numberofListings];
        next = 0;
    }


    public void addListing(Listing newListing) {
        if (next < data.length) {
            data[next] = newListing;
            next++;
        }else{                                                         // facultative
            System.out.println("Invalid operation -> array is full");  // it is
        }                                                              // juste informative
    }

    public void showAllListing() {
        for (int i = 0; i < next; i++) {   //print only not empty boxes, stop to 'next'
            System.out.println(data[i]);
        }
    }    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DataStructure obj1 = new DataStructure(100);

        Listing l1 = new Listing();
        obj1.addListing(l1);             //next = 0; set item to 0 positon, then next = 1
        obj1.addListing(new Listing());  //next = 1; set item to 1 positon, then next = 2

        obj1.showAllListing();
    }
}
```

---

Improvements :

- when you'll be more familiar with Java, you may take a look to `List<>` which allows dynamic size

Comment: @azro-At the command prompt, isn't supposed to print Name:  Age: 0 not two times but 100 times?

Comment: @dorakta if you fill the array with only 2 elements it will only print you 2 times because after there are only `null` elements, but if you want 100 times print, replace he "i<next" by "i<data.length" in the fort loop